# FlashBuilder PersistenceManager working on devices, but not in Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I am using FlashBuilder 4.6 for building Mobile applications.
I am using PersistenceManager and it works great on all devices (phew..)
My problem is in my Windows computer - it does not save anything. The function calls are successful, but when I relaunch my app in Windows, it's like nothing had been saved.

```
private var saveManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();
saveManager.setProperty("Radiohead", "Thomyourke");
saveManager.save();
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is for Air/mobile only. Use the SharedObject in case of web applications.